# why use Databinding?

Tags: android, data-binding

i have an android application project which i have been developing for last 4 months and now i heard about DataBinding which i reckon is a useful method for a better communication between data and UI. so i am asking is that do i have or need to change all my code to Databinding Syntax, i mean is it necessary or will it make my application more secure. what are the pros and cons of using DataBinding in my case.

i have read somewhere that it will minimize the code and i dont have to write findviewbyid for every view or settext in most of the cases.

Comment: "do i have or need to change all my code to Databinding Syntax" -- only where you want to use data binding. "is it necessary" -- no. "will it make my application more secure" -- no. "i have read somewhere that it will minimize the code and i dont have to write findviewbyid for every view or settext in most of the cases" -- correct. I recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBbeQMOcnZ0) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAmMN7m3wLU) to learn why data binding may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding will save you some code but I don't think that it's a good enough reason to do all the extra work.
DataBinding will update your UI according to values of data in the code, therefore it's worth moving to DataBinding if you have data that you want to display to the user and is being updated from non-UI threads.
In this case, moving to DataBinding will save you bugs as a result of UI updating methods (such as `notifyDatasetChanged()`) not being called when the data gets updated.

EDIT:
DataBinding has nothing to do with security but it will (for now) prevent you from using the new [jack toolchain](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a good reason to update all of previous codes to work with data binding except when you want to apply big changes to that part of app for example a fragment or a view.(If something is working don't mess it) And you can use data binding in new layouts.
For start working with libraries like data binding start with simple code. Changing a previously wrote code to data binding needs to master on it.